# What kind of data should be stored on database in a blog website

Tags: database

I am creating a blog website where user can post articles about anything tech related. The article can have multiple images and multiple different paragraphs with markdowns and styles applied to some of them. I want to make it dynamic but I am unable to think about the database design.

Should I make a column named `content` with `text` type and store the entire post in it? if so then how am I supposed to stylize it as it is in one big variable. Also how do I display images if they are inside one field mixed with the post content.

Is there any other way to make it dynamic and still being able to style different elements? The thing to keep in mind here is the post sometimes might have 3 paragraphs or 4 or 5 and same goes for images

Answer (score -1):

Storing the entire post content in a single text field might not be the most efficient approach, especially if you want to maintain flexibility for styling and handling images. Here's a suggestion for a more structured database design:

Posts Table: This table will store information about each post, such as the post ID, title, author, publication date, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
    post_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    publication_date DATE NOT NULL,
    -- Other fields as needed
);
```

Paragraphs Table: This table will store the paragraphs of each post individually, linked to the post they belong to.

```
CREATE TABLE Paragraphs (
    paragraph_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    -- Other fields as needed
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES Posts(post_id)
);
```

With this design, each paragraph and each image is stored as a separate record in the database, allowing you to handle them individually and apply styles dynamically. You can use the post_id to associate each paragraph and image with the corresponding post.

When retrieving a post, you would query the Paragraphs and Images tables using the post_id to get all the paragraphs and images associated with that post. Then, you can render them accordingly in your blog website, applying styles as needed.

This design offers flexibility for handling posts of varying lengths and structures, as each paragraph and image is stored separately. Additionally, it allows for easy querying and manipulation of post content.

Comment: Please don't post AI-generated content.

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt Well, for starters, you look for answers that are utter nonsense. Splitting a post into paragraphs and storing them separately does nothing to help you "stylize" it or display images. It wouldn't make anything better, and it would make a ton of things worse. And there is absolutely no way in which it "allows for easy querying and manipulation of post content".